# Android - Fragment with two buttons

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on building an Android application that has a fragment with two buttons, either "News" or "Social". It gets initialised with news, and then if "Social" button is clicked during runtime, it should refresh the fragment with the social's relevant content. Is there a way to do that?

[image: Print screen showing what i want to achieve]

Comment: change the fragment in button click event

Comment: what you implemented so far? Did you already tried? the question should be more targeted to the specific problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is putting two views on the fragment and show/hide properly:

```
<!-- News -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/news_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- News content -->

    </FrameLayout>

<!-- Social -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/social_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Social content -->

</FrameLayout>
```

Then, on Java, you use these containers:

```
// show news and hide social example
socialContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE)
newsContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by setting to values of ui elements in on click listener of buttons and pass the respective content of the clicked button. But in case you want to represent information differently then you need to make container layouts and set visibility according to the button clicked.

Answer (score 0):

In your news tab you can achieve the same by following code

```
newsBtn.setOncliclListener(this);
socialBtn.setOncliclListener(this);
```

and in your onclick method write down the code for updating your view according to btn click

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.newsbtn:
             socailview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             newsview.setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE);
             loadYourNewsViewData();
              break;
            case R.id.socialbtn:
            newsview.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
            socailview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

             loadYourSocialViewData();
            break;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code in your main activity to load news fragment as first fragment

```
<fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="name of your news fragment class"
            android:id="@+id/newsFragment"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would:

1. Make a container `Fragment` (just those two buttons of yours), which contains a `FrameLayout`.
2. Make a base abstract class of `BaseNewsFragment`, which is going to be a parent for your `NewsFragment` and `SocialFragment`.
3. Dependent of which button was clicked, I would call a method to replace a content of the `FrameLayout` with an argument of specific fragment